# Iterate through an array - returned error "Attempted to access A(:,3); index out of bounds because size(A)=[4,2]"

Tags: arrays, excel, matlab, loops, size

I am new to MATLAB and I am trying to write some code to iterate through an imported Excel array and do a calculation on each column of the array separately.  I am receiving the error "Attempted to access A(:,3); index out of bounds because size(A)=[4,2]" and I am not sure why, as I have tried to give the output variable matrix dimensions.  Here is the code:

```
filename = 'allsets.xlsx';
x1Range = 'B1:C5';
sheet = 1;
A = xlsread(filename,sheet,x1Range);
Mu1 = zeros(size(A));
Mu2 = zeros(size(B));
for i = 1:length(A)
   % class mean
    Mu1(:,i)=mean(A(:,i))';
end 
x2Range = 'B6:C9';
B = xlsread(filename,sheet,x2Range);
for i = 1:length(B)
    Mu2(:,i)=mean(B(:,i))';
end
```

Any suggestions on how to address this error would be very appreciated.  Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

use `size(A,2)` instead of `length(A)`. `length` returns the size of the largest dimension, which is the number of rows in your case

Answer (score 2):

`length` gives you the size in the dimension where a matrix is the longest. In your case, `A` is 3x2, so `length` returns 3, yet you are looping along the second dimension.